# proper way to handle these RESTful calls for handling state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, design-patterns

So, I have done a couple of projects where a call comes up for toggling state on an item. It is usually like whether an item is enabled or liked or something similar. It has to be a binary element though.

I have usually said that the proper way to do this is posting / deleting but that a quicker way is to do something like

```
/api/toggle_enabled/23/item
```

or

```
/api/toggle_liked/28/item
```

and have the state be reconciled on the server and return in the response the resulting state like:

```
{
 id:23,
 is_enabled: true / false
}
```

or

```
{
 id:28,
 is_liked: true / false
}
```

Usually other developers groan (as do I) when I see this but has always worked well and simplified client-side code by handling things like state for a user pressing a button multiple times very quickly. How do other developers handle this type of situation and is there another good option for handling? I know that this breaks RESTful principles but the simplicity seems to be worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends. Because REST is stateless such problem arises and are very common in API's world.

The way you handled this scenario is commonly applied and however I personally don't like it, I tolerate it because it's easy and simple. Below you can find alternative scenarios of handling such cases.

1. If you'd like to stick to REST rules you should **PUT** all the entity every time to `/api/item/28` with `liked` set appropriately. This request should return the whole modified entity.
2. If you don't want to send whole entity every time **PATCH** is the way to go. Using **PATCH** only modified fields are sent along with the request to the same endpoint. Mind the fact the in contrast to **PUT**, **PATCH** is not idempotent. This request should return whole entity or no content.
3. When more advanced scenarios come into play (e.g. there might be multiple likes) **POST** *definitely* should be used to e.g. increase the likes count or like/dislike. Request should be send to `/api/items/28/like|dislike`. Why **POST**? Since this is an *operation* on the resource - verb is used instead of noun. Such request should return modified entity to track the state.
4. This is an extension of 3 - not only you track all the likes but likes can be deleted, commented etc. In this case you introduce a new resource: `/likes` and **POST** new like to this endpoint - in response new like is returned. Use **GET** for simple filtering of `/likes` collection or **POST** `/likes/filter` if advance filtering is required.

Comment: thx for response. So for me, if I were to POST likes/:item_id/:item_type and have it just change the state, it would be similar to the my toggle_as_liked/:item_id/:item_type and similar to your 4th scenario?

Comment: In your case it would be **POST** to `likes` with all the necessary data carried in body.